# Length of a segment

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a course I am following, the instructor defines a subset of the natural numbersm $\mathbb{N}$
  as: $$J_n=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$$
  where $J_n$
  is defined as a segment of $\mathbb{N}$.
  Then, he makes the following statement:

Take 2 segments $J_m$
  and $J_n$. $J_m\approx J_n \text{ iff } m=n$.
  Here, $\approx$
  corresponds to numerical equivalence of sets. What does $m=n$
  mean in this case? Does it mean that the sequence is of the exact same numbers? If you consider: $$J_m=(10,11,\ldots,n+9)$$
  and $J_n$
  as before, we still have numerical equivalence, but $m\neq n$.
  What exactly does a 'segment' mean in this case? The length of the sequence, or the sequence itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally segments are defined to be sets $I$ of numbers such that for every $a,b\in I$, if $a<c<b$ then $c\in I$.

My understanding of the claim is that the $J_n$ are defined to be not arbitrary segments of length $n$, but rather the concrete segment which starts at $0$.

Then the claim is that segments starting at $0$ and which have the same length end in the same number, which is perfectly reasonable.